# Randomizing a value inside a component of a list of tuples

Tags: python, random, tuples

Ok, so I want to randomize a value from a component that belongs to a list of tuples. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
tuples=[('green', 40.0079), ('black', 50.0026), ('white', 60.941), ('yellow', 90.01218)]
```

So, here I want to return "black" for example, not "black 50.0026". So I just want the first parameter to be randomized!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us what you've tried already, and explain why it doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: What does the "first parameter to be randomized" mean? do you mean you want to shuffle the list and return a random element from the list?

Comment: "So, here I want to return "black" for example, not "black 50.0026"" Well, if you got `('black', 50.0026)` back as a result, can you see how you could get `"black"` out of that? If you take those two steps (picking the tuple, and then picking an element from it), does that solve your problem? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for a single random selection in the tuples list that will only return the first component of the selected item:

If that is the case, then the choice function (from the random module) should do the job.  You only need to to get the first component after the selection:

```
import random

random.choice(tuples)[0]
```

On the other hand if what you want is to shuffle the colors around across the tuples, you can separate the tuples into two distinct lists using zip, shuffle the colors and reassemble the two parts (using zip again):

```
import random

colors,values = zip(*tuples)
tuples = list(zip(random.sample(colors,len(colors)),values))

print(tuples)
[('black', 40.0079), ('white', 50.0026), ('green', 60.941), 
 ('yellow', 90.01218)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes this did the trick :)